Нужна ли запятая после "кот"?
По нашему двору рыскает чужой кот(?) и будет рыскать, пока не поймает канарейку.


По правилам нет знака перед одиночным союзом И (однородные сказуемые в главной части)

По нашему двору рыскает чужой кот и будет рыскать, пока не поймает канарейку.

Но желательно поставить тире для обозначения паузы:

По нашему двору рыскает чужой кот — и будет рыскать, пока не поймает канарейку.

А как же присоединительные контрукции? "Передавая им эти сведения, он поступил нехорошо, и  знал это". "Но я не стал возражать, и  хорошо сделал, а то она могла бы обидеться". https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/

Я не вижу здесь присоединительного значения – вторая часть, как я думаю, входит в ОСНОВНОЕ содержание предложения. А иначе непонятно, что хотел сказать автор в первой части. Или нужно привести контекст, чтобы это было понятно. А пока я слышу так: По двору ходит кот, которому нужно поймать добычу.   По лесу рыщет, добычу ищет!  (Загадка). //  В приведенных примерах даются комментарии автора по поводу ситуации, а это присоединительные отношения.
